# AWS S3 JavaScript SDK getSignedUrl returns base path only

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have some very simple code for generating an S3 URL.  The URL I get back from the SDK only has the base path for S3.  It doesn't contain anything else.  Why is this happening?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

console.log(s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
  Bucket: 'test',
  Key: 'test'
}));

// Returns "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

Node.js v0.12.0, AWS SDK 2.1.15 or 2.1.17, Windows 7 64-bit,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem wasn't with code.  It turns out that when you don't have your AWS credentials set up properly in your environment that the AWS SDK doesn't complain.  Fixing the credentials in `~/.aws/credentials` resolved the issue.

Comment: i have assigned IAM Role [S3 Full access policy ] to EC2 in console still am getting same issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I inserted a correct access token, but some requests received only basepath, and some requests received normal URLs.

I was able to get the correct URL when I modified `getSignedUrl` to `await getSignedUrlPromise`.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. I got the correct output by changing the below

from `AWS_Access_Key_Id = myaccesskey` to `aws_access_key_id=myaccesskey`

Similarly for Secret key. That means you should not use Upper case and no space before and after `=`

Answer (score 0):

To trace your issue whether your bucket exists with right permissions, and/or credentials are correct in your ~/.aws/credentials file, or whatever other aws access related problems. I just used the (Headbucket) operation as per documentation.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrlPromise-property

to achieve this programmatically:

```js
/* This operation checks to see if a bucket exists. Put into aws.ts files*/

var params = {
    Bucket: "acl1"
};
s3.headBucket(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Meanwhile the callback:

```js
var params = {
  Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  ExpectedBucketOwner: 'STRING_VALUE'  /* the owner's aws account id */
};
s3.headBucket(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

This will throw an exception like:

> for example => CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE...